# How do I check for updates for my AMD Radeon 5870 Graphics card?

Tags: drivers, ati, updates, graphics, radeon

I am new to the whole Linux OS and the differences when it comes to updating software on the laptop I have. So, without further ado, my question!

I followed this link here to get the driver for my Radeon HD 5870 graphics card:

https://www.kubuntuforums.net/archive/index.php/t-64125.html

I was successful, but now I wonder. How do I check for updates for the drivers? I have the Catalyst control center for my Linux, which is 64bit, but I don't understand how to make it check for updates.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://support.amd.com/en-us/download and use the options available there.

1 Desktop Graphics
2 Radeon HD series
3 Radeon HD 5xxx PCIe
4 Linux 64-bit